# Ternary search tree implementation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I have implemented a Ternary search tree. It works well. But if you think something needs to be improved, say it. This code was tested in Python 3.7.4.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, character):
        self.character = character
        self.leftNode = None
        self.middleNode = None
        self.rightNode = None
        self.value = 0

class TST(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rootNode = None

    def put(self,key,value):
        self.rootNode = self.putItem(self.rootNode, key, value, 0)

    def putItem(self, node, key, value, index):

        c = key[index]

        if node == None:
            node = Node(c)

        if c < node.character:
            node.leftNode = self.putItem(node.leftNode, key, value, index)
        elif c > node.character:
            node.rightNode = self.putItem(node.rightNode, key, value, index)
        elif index < len(key) - 1:
            node.middleNode = self.putItem(node.middleNode, key, value, index+1)
        else:
            node.value = value

        return node

    def get(self, key):

        node = self.getItem(self.rootNode, key, 0)

        if node == None:
            return -1

        return node.value

    def getItem(self, node, key, index):

        if node == None:
            return None

        c = key[index]

        if c < node.character:
            return self.getItem(node.leftNode, key, index)
        elif c > node.character:
            return self.getItem(node.rightNode, key, index)
        elif index < len(key) - 1:
            return self.getItem(node.middleNode, key, index+1)
        else:
            return node

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tst = TST()

    tst.put("apple",100)
    tst.put("orange",200)

    print( tst.get("orange") )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data structure-wise, it seems okay, and does what you're after.

Code-style wise, I see a few things:

1. It's not quite [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the coding style. Whilst you can read it, which is always good, there are tools to automatize the process, such as [`flake8`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/), [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black). Most likely, your editor will have a plugin.

   This is include things like `underscore_names` in lieu of `camelCasing`.

   Note that this standard is a living document, and gets updated once in a while.
2. `None` is a singleton in Python, and thus you can use the `is` keyword instead.
   Python relies on its `id()` function to get a hash of an object, and compare them.
   As `None` is a singleton, the hash is the same.

   So your line `if node == None:` could be `if node is None`.
   <strike>Going further this way, `None` evaluates to `False` in a test, so you could go `if not node:`</strike> (edit: as discussed with @Gloweye, it's indeed clearer and preferred to use the first variant).
3. Python returns `None` when no value is being explicitly returned, whether you have no `return` in a function, or do a blank `return`.

These two lines taken together could then be:

```py
if node is None:
    return
```

and would be considered idiomatic.

4. Lastly, in Python3 (which you ought to be using), class definition have been revamped. The way you do it:

```py
class TST(object):
```

is now:

```py
class TST:
```

If you were inheriting from something, though, it would indeed be:

```py
class TST(ParentClass):
```

Maybe what you could try next is to implement unit tests with [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) or [pytest](https://pytest.org/en/latest/) and see whether your structure holds on with more convoluted cases.

Comment: In Python, if you're actively looking for None instead of falsy value in general, `if node is None` is preferred to `if not node`. This applies to this specific case.

Comment: You're right, and I abuse that behaviour. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: The point isn't for the computer running the code, it's for the programmer reading it. When they read `if not node`, they'll wander what node can be other than Node or None. `if node is None` instead shows you that Nodes and None are the only valid values. That makes it more readable, and especially here on CodeReview, therefore preferable.

Comment: Thank a lot Gloweye and Cyril D. to spend your valuable time to get the review of my code. Let me correct as per your suggestion and get back to you. Today I learned many coding fundamentals and styles from your suggestions. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0):

## Docstring

You can document the behaviour of the method with a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

## typing

You can add typing, to clarify for the caller what type the different arguments and variables are

## `TST.putItem`

Apart from the name, which according to PEP-8 would be better as `put_item`, should not be an ordinary method of the TST.  The `self` is only used as to recursively call the same method. This can be a helper method in the global namespace, or a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

The same comment goes for the `GetItem`

## `get`

```
def get(self, key):

    node = self.getItem(self.rootNode, key, 0)

    if node == None:
        return -1

    return node.value
```

-1 is a bad sentinel value. How will the caller distinguish between a `node.value` of `-1` or a non-existent key?

Better would be to either raise a `KeyError` if the value is not in the tree, or mimic the behaviour of [`dict.get(key\[, default_value\])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), with an explicit default value.

## tuple unpacking

Instead of explicitly sending the index with it, you can use tuple unpacking.

---

My take on your Ternary search tree:

With added typing hints, implementing the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` magic methods.

The `put_item` and `get_item` can be put on the `Node` class as well. Which you choose is a matter of taste

```
import typing

V = typing.TypeVar("V")


class Node:
    def __init__(
        self, character: str, value: typing.Optional[V] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.character: str = character
        self.left: typing.Optional[Node] = None
        self.middle: typing.Optional[Node] = None
        self.right: typing.Optional[Node] = None
        self.value: typing.Optional[V] = value


class TernarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root: typing.Optional[Node] = None

    def __setitem__(
        self, key: typing.Union[str, typing.Iterable[str]], value: V
    ) -> None:
        self.root = TernarySearchTree.put_item(self.root, key=key, value=value)

    put = __setitem__

    @staticmethod
    def put_item(
        node: typing.Optional[Node],
        key: typing.Union[str, typing.Iterable[str]],
        value: V,
    ) -> Node:
        c: str
        c, *rest = key

        if node is None:
            node = Node(c)

        if c < node.character:
            node.left = TernarySearchTree.put_item(
                node=node.left, key=key, value=value
            )
        elif c > node.character:
            node.right = TernarySearchTree.put_item(
                node=node.right, key=key, value=value
            )
        elif rest:
            node.middle = TernarySearchTree.put_item(
                node=node.middle, key=rest, value=value
            )
        else:
            node.value = value
        return node

    def __getitem__(self, key: typing.Union[str, typing.Iterable[str]]) -> V:
        return TernarySearchTree.get_item(self.root, key=key).value

    def get(
        self,
        key: typing.Union[str, typing.Iterable[str]],
        default_value: typing.Optional[V] = None,
    ) -> typing.Optional[V]:
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default_value

    @staticmethod
    def get_item(
        node: typing.Optional[Node],
        key: typing.Union[str, typing.Iterable[str]],
    ) -> Node:
        if node is None:
            raise KeyError

        c: str
        c, *rest = key

        if c == node.character and not rest:
            return node

        if c < node.character:
            return TernarySearchTree.get_item(node=node.left, key=key)
        if c > node.character:
            return TernarySearchTree.get_item(node=node.right, key=key)
        return TernarySearchTree.get_item(node=node.middle, key=rest)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    tst = TernarySearchTree()

    tst.put("apple", 100)
    tst["orange"] = 200
    tst.put("orb", 150)

    print(tst["orange"])
```